# Tortoise SVN noui command not working?

Tags: batch-file, tortoisesvn

I am running an automated update command from a batch file and I am using the command line prompt for TortoiseSVN, I don't want any pop up windows to be displayed. I have tried the commmand /noui however it seems it doesn't work. Is there any way to execute an update or clean process without the UI popping up? I currently have something like this below...

```
TortoiseProc.exe" /command:cleanup /path:"%SOURCETrunk%" /url:"%URLTrunk%" /closeonend:3 /nodlg /noui
```

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the Tortoise SVN command line client. It is an option on installing of the latest release of Tortoise SVN. There I can call the normal svn update command straight from the command line and no UI windows will appear.

Change to the working directory then just run the "svn update" command